# Declaration conflict due to different opencv version while compiling

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am getting the following error while trying to build the `lsd-slam_noros` package. On whole this package depends on two other packages `openFABmap`  and `g2o`, both compile without error. When compiling the lsd-slam module I'm getting the following error.

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp:48:0,
                 from /home/vivJune_2019/lsd_slam_noros-master/thirdparty/openFabMap/include/bowmsctrainer.hpp:58,
                 from /home/vivJune_2019/lsd_slam_noros-master/thirdparty/openFabMap/include/openfabmap.hpp:59,
                 from /home/vivJune_2019/lsd_slam_noros-master/lsd_slam/global_mapping/fab_map.cc:41:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp:231:19: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef class cv::Feature2D cv::FeatureDetector’
 typedef Feature2D FeatureDetector;
                   ^
In file included from /home/vivJune_2019/lsd_slam_noros-master/lsd_slam/global_mapping/fab_map.cc:22:0:
/home/vivJune_2019/lsd_slam_noros-master/lsd_slam/global_mapping/fab_map.h:29:7: note: previous declaration as ‘class cv::FeatureDetector’
 class FeatureDetector;
```

It error suggests a declaration problem in file `bowmsctrainer.hpp` as compared to declaration in `fab_map.h` (?). I'm not sure how do resolve this declaration conflict.

**Please help!**

Here is a more complete log from the build process (bowmsctrainer is built before the current part)

```
Scanning dependencies of target openFABMAP
[  2%] Building CXX object thirdparty/openFabMap/CMakeFiles/openFABMAP.dir/src/inference.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object thirdparty/openFabMap/CMakeFiles/openFABMAP.dir/src/chowliutree.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object thirdparty/openFabMap/CMakeFiles/openFABMAP.dir/src/msckd.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object thirdparty/openFabMap/CMakeFiles/openFABMAP.dir/src/bowmsctrainer.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object thirdparty/openFabMap/CMakeFiles/openFABMAP.dir/src/fabmap.cpp.o
[ 17%] Linking CXX static library ../../../lib/libopenFABMAP.a
[ 17%] Built target openFABMAP
Scanning dependencies of target lsd_slam
[ 20%] Building CXX object lsd_slam/CMakeFiles/lsd_slam.dir/depth_estimation/depth_map_pixel_hypothesis.cc.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object lsd_slam/CMakeFiles/lsd_slam.dir/depth_estimation/depth_map.cc.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object lsd_slam/CMakeFiles/lsd_slam.dir/global_mapping/trackable_key_frame_search.cc.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object lsd_slam/CMakeFiles/lsd_slam.dir/global_mapping/g2o_type_sim3_sophus.cc.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object lsd_slam/CMakeFiles/lsd_slam.dir/global_mapping/fab_map.cc.o

In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp:48:0,
                 from /home/vivJune_2019/lsd_slam_noros-master/thirdparty/openFabMap/include/bowmsctrainer.hpp:58,
                 from /home/vivJune_2019/lsd_slam_noros-master/thirdparty/openFabMap/include/openfabmap.hpp:59,
                 from /home/vivJune_2019/lsd_slam_noros-master/lsd_slam/global_mapping/fab_map.cc:41:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp:231:19: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef class cv::Feature2D cv::FeatureDetector’
 typedef Feature2D FeatureDetector;
                   ^
In file included from /home/vivJune_2019/lsd_slam_noros-master/lsd_slam/global_mapping/fab_map.cc:22:0:
/home/vivJune_2019/lsd_slam_noros-master/lsd_slam/global_mapping/fab_map.h:29:7: note: previous declaration as ‘class cv::FeatureDetector’
 class FeatureDetector;
```

The relevant (partial) content of `fab_map.h` (probably) is :

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

namespace of2 {
class FabMap;
}
namespace cv {
    class FeatureDetector;
    class BOWImgDescriptorExtractor;
}
```

Comment: What are you exactly asking us? How to fix lsd-slam code? Or how to build it with OpenCV 2.4.8 it wants, instead of the newer version you have?

Comment: @Kit. Thanks for your response. I am trying to fix the lsd-slam myself. I also realize that I am using a newer version of OpenCV. I fix these errors one by one and this error has something to do with difference of declarations at two places (?). I am not able to understand which declaration is causing the error.

Comment: The type `FeatureDetector` in the newer OpenCV2 is defined as a `typedef` and not a `class`. The proper fix would be to include a relevant header instead of this manual "forward declaration".